# How can I get the data of particular collection of mongodb?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

In the below cole, in 4th line, Messages is my collection name of mongodb which I created on other file. And if I find the data of this collection then no error is occuring.

But when I am writing other collection name of mongodb which I created manually on mongodb website then it is giving error.

```js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Pusher from "pusher";
import Messages from "./messages.js";
import dynamicModel from "./messagesRoom.js";
import cors from "cors";

// app configuration

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// DB Configuration

const url = "mongodb+srv://suraj_bisht_99:zoe6B82AZjaLXgw7@cluster0.zp9dc.mongodb.net/Whatsapp_MERN";
mongoose.connect(url, {useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
        .then(()=> console.log('mongoDB is connected'))
        .then(err => console.log(err));


// API routes

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello World");
})


app.get("/messages/sync", async (req, res) => {
        await other__collection.find( (err, data) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }else{
                res.status(200).send(data);
            }
        })
})


app.post("/messages/new", async (req, res) => {
     
    try{
        const newMessage = new Messages(req.body);
        const newMessageCreated = await newMessage.save();
        res.status(201).send(newMessageCreated);
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
});

// listening part 

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port number ${port}`));
```

My question is how can I get the data of other collections of mongoDB in the same way as I am getting with the collection which I made on other file

This is my Message collection.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const messageSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
      message: String,
      name: String,
      timestamp: String,
      received: Boolean,
});

const messageContent = mongoose.model('messageContent', messageSchema);

export default messageContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `mongoose`, you have to create a Schema and a Model for each collection, and then you can query MongoDB with that Model.

So, create a Schema and a Model for that other collection like you did with `messageContent` and use that Model when you query DB.

Comment: I have done this what you are saying, I have not shown that part in my code but I have done that. But even then I am unable to get data of those collections.